# Wiping all my Google Play achievements in the OAuth2 Playground doesn't wipe my achievements

Tags: google-play, oauth2-playground, google-play-developer-api

If I go and unlock an achievement in game, and then run a reset, after running through the OAuth process for my user, posting to `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1management/achievements/reset`, I receive a correct response,

```
{
  "kind": "gamesManagement#achievementResetAllResponse", 
  "results": [
    {
      "definitionId": "CgkIh9rSofwUEAIQAQ", 
      "kind": "gamesManagement#achievementResetResponse", 
      "updateOccurred": true, 
      "currentState": "REVEALED"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I post to `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1management/achievements/reset` again, again I get a successful empty list response, as is expected,

```
{
"kind": "gamesManagement#achievementResetAllResponse", 
"results": []
}
```

But when I go back into the game, check my achievements, it still shows that I have that achievement.  No matter if I log out, log in, restart the app, makes no difference, I still have that achievement,

[image]

Even if I post the full reset, `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1management/achievements/resetAllForAllPlayers`, I get the successful, no body response,

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Etag: "aHcpPO1q3J7BuZyftdPIkrurI0I/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 15:14:31 GMT
```